# another AsyncTask issue - inner class can't see doInBackground method

Tags: android, json, class, android-asynctask

There's obviously something I'm missing here - I've been through the developer.android reference and guide material on AsyncTasks and threads - plus scores of posts here, and it's not my first rodeo either.
I have an inner AsyncTask Class that grabs JSON from a url and parses it. I keep running into access issues and can't seem to get the right combination. Here's a chunk of code partway through the main public class, which is "Consumer". I can ad more code, but I believe this will demonstrate what's needed. TIA!

```
// some method
if(arg1==b){
    b.setClickable(false);  
    a.setClickable(true); 
    // next, build the url
    srchStr = urla + "&q=upc:" + value1 + urlc;
    // execute the parser
    new JSONParser().execute(value1);
}

// ...

static class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    static InputStream is = null; 
    static JSONObject jObj = null; 
    static String json = "";      


    public JSONObject doInBackground(String url) {    //getJSONFromUrl
        // Making HTTP request 
        try { 
            // defaultHttpClient 
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);    
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
            is = httpEntity.getContent();            

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        try { 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = null; 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                sb.append(line + "\n"); 
            } 
            is.close(); 
            json = sb.toString(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString()); 
        } 

        // try to parse the string to a JSON object 
        try { 
            jObj = new JSONObject(json); 
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
        } 

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj;      
    } 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setText("json"); // txt.setText(result);


    }       
}
```

The error comes up on the line:

```
static class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
```

which is:

> The type Consumer.JSONParser must implement the inherited abstract
>   method   AsyncTask.doInBackground(String...)

....yet, the doInBackground method is there.....

I hope this is sufficient info to troubleshoot this. I expect it is something simple that I have been missing....

Update:
I made the recommended changes, as they certainly made sense, however it now compiles, but won't run. Please take another look and let me know if I am mistaken, or if this is another issue...
Here's the updated code:

```
if(arg1==b){
    b.setClickable(false);  
    a.setClickable(true); 
    // next, build the url
    srchStr = urla + "&q=upc:" + value1 + urlc;
    // execute the parser
    new JSONParser().execute(value1);
    }   
}

    static class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    static InputStream is = null; 
    static JSONObject jObj = null; 
    static String json = "";      


     public JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {       //getJSONFromUrl
         Consumer.srchStr = urls[0];
        // Making HTTP request 
        try { 
            // defaultHttpClient 
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(srchStr);    
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
            is = httpEntity.getContent();            

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        try { 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = null; 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                sb.append(line + "\n"); 
            } 
            is.close(); 
            json = sb.toString(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString()); 
        } 

        // try to parse the string to a JSON object 
        try { 
            jObj = new JSONObject(json); 
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
        } 

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj;      
    } 
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        //TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        result = jObj;
        tv2.setText("result"); // txt.setText(result);          
    }       
}
}
```

and the logcat text:

```
12-29 21:35:25.530: W/dalvikvm(2237): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at com.clicsys.pbuster.Consumer$JSONParser.doInBackground(Consumer.java:116)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at com.clicsys.pbuster.Consumer$JSONParser.doInBackground(Consumer.java:1)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-29 21:35:25.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is line 116 of Consumer? Also double check what you're passing to your AsyncTask, is it properly formatted to what `httpClient` wants?

Comment: 116: HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: you pass of `value1` to your AsyncTask, when maybe you need to pass off `srchStr` since I see that has more formatting. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but maybe that's why `httpClient` is throwing fits.

Comment: Ahhh...my error was in 115, which s/b:                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);.....is this what you mean?

Comment: Well `httpClient` complains about something being wrong, and `httpPost` is what you pass to `execute` so most likely. Double check to see if that's valid (not that I know how to do that, I haven't worked with these classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your method signature so it is

```
public JSONObject doInBackground(String... url)
```

This is because [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) accepts in an infinite amount of arguments. To acess the `String` you want, you can then do

```
String currentUrl = url [0];
```

Also, your onPostExecute needs a `JSONObject` as the argument. This will not use the `...` because `onPostExecute()` only accepts in 1 argument.

Comment: if OP add `@override` before `doInBackground` then i think all issue get solved

Comment: adding `@override` will cause about the same error telling you that `doInBackground(String)` does not override any supertype method since that is `doInBackground(String...)` (nearly equivalent to `doInBackground(String[])`)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Eclipse should do that even without deleting the wrong method since the required one is missing. `doInBackground(String)` is just like any other method you can add to your implementation since it has a different signature (method name + parameters)